# get notification when systemd-monitored service enters failed state

Tags: linux, bash, service, systemd

I need to have network messages sent when a systemd service I have crashes or is hung (i.e., enters failed state; I monitor for hung by using WatchdogSec=). I noticed that newer systemd have FailureAction=, but then saw that this doesn't allow arbitrary commands, but just rebooting/shutdown.

Specifically, I need a way to have one network message sent when systemd detects the program has crashed, and another when it detects it has hung.

I'm hoping for a better answer than "parse the logs", and I need something that has a near-instant response time, so I don't think a polling approach is good; it should be something triggered by the event occurring.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

systemd units support OnFailure that will activate a unit (or more) when the unit goes to failed. You can put something like

```
 OnFailure=notify-failed@%n
```

And then create the `notify-failed@.service` service where you can use the required [specifier](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers)  (you probably will want at least %i) to launch the script or command that will send notification.

You can see a practical example in http://northernlightlabs.se/systemd.status.mail.on.unit.failure

Comment: There are a couple corrections needed to the instructions on the linked site. First, `notify%n.service` is redundant, and will result in `notify@my-service.service.service`. Second, `%i` should be used instead of `%I`, or all dashes in the name will be converted to forward slashes.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for multiple or all units, without modifying their unit files?

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev - you don't need to modify the actual unit files - you can just add an override for that specific feature. For example, run `systemctl edit my-service.service` and in the editor that opens add  a line `[Unit]` followed by `OnFailure=notify-failed@%n`, save and exit. This will create an override file in `/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service.d/override.conf` with the added functionality (of course you can automate the creation of such files for multiple services, just don't forget to do `systemctl daemon-reload` if you modified files not through `systemctl`).

Comment: For anybody looking to do this for all service files at once, check **Example 3** at the very end of [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). You need to place a configuration under `service.d` directory and it will apply to all services.

Comment: @Felipe - I tried that on an Ubuntu 18.04 system but can't get it to work as advertised. The `OnFailure= failure-handler@%n.service ` does work when attached to the individual service's `[Unit]` section but not when `/etc/systemd/system/service.d/10-all.conf` is the only place it is defined.

Comment: @Felipe - ...adding to my own comment, it seems that top-level drop-ins need `systemd` version [244](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v244/man/systemd.unit.xml#L195) or newer and Ubuntu 18 only has version 237.

Answer (score 34):

Just my way to notify :

/etc/systemd/system/notify-email@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Sent email 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/systemctl status %i | /usr/bin/mailx -Ssendwait -s "[SYSTEMD_%i] Fail" your_admin@company.blablabla'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

add to systemd:

```
systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/notify-email@.service
```

At others services add:

```
[Unit]
OnFailure=notify-email@%i.service
```

Reload the configuration:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid triggering it lots of times in a row? In some situations receiving 1K emails about a service that failed at night and tried over and over again to restart itself isn't helpful.

Comment: As far I know, no, there is no option from systemd. You should put some control into the bash command, something like touching a file and checking if it have +10min for example... in simple command logic: find -mmin +10 && send email && touch file ;

Comment: Why are you enabling the notification service? It's supposed to be started by other units, no reason to start it on boot.

Comment: `/bin/bash` instead of `/usr/bin/bash`

Comment: I'm a newbie here, but what I read at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html (Example 3. Top level drop-ins with template units) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506374/16256 makes me wonder if the `WantedBy=multi-user.target` line is unnecessary or unwanted. Would it cause this to send a notification at each boot?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this utility which seems to provide this: https://github.com/joonty/systemd_mon

Comment: Have you tried it? Last commit is many years old, it seems.